# UiPath wont recognize textbox and other controls within userform

Tags: automation, uipath

I have been working on UiPath for quite some time and I have a form where I need to input certain details.

UiPath won't recognize the controls within the form. This form is designed using power builder and the selector looks something as below

```
<wnd app='pcemain.exe' cls='FNWNS390' title='Open' /> 
<wnd cls='pbdw90' />
```

[image]

Comment: Does the items and their order differ from time to time? Or is it always the same items, in the same order?

Comment: Controls wont change and it will always remain same order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the items and their order in the list won't change; you should be able to use the `Send Hotkey` activity or `Type into` activity, or a combination of the two.

In some dropdowns, you can type the whole name of the item.

> My tip for these kinds of situations, where the (mouse) controls are
>   challenging, is to try to do the action manually without using the
>   mouse (or use it as little as possible). When finding a solution, do
>   it in UiPath