# UiPath wont recognize textbox and other controls within Power builder forms

Tags: automation, ui-automation, uipath, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-activity

Facing issues in Power builder apps where in UiPath is not able to identify individual elements.
It is treating the whole form as 1 elements only.

Hence I am not able to automated. Is there any work around if anyone is aware of ?

Comment: I believe your question is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340891/uipath-wont-recognize-textbox-and-other-controls-within-userform

Alternatively you can try Citrix/Image automation to automate Power-Builder apps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using Computer Vision for this to see if it picks up the elements individually?